# what's the correct command use vim copy to clipboard as the clipboard supported version has installed?

Tags: vim, clipboard, yank

I'm using `Manjaro`, and open clipboard:

```
➜  ~ vim --version | grep "clipboard"
+clipboard      +jumplist      +persistent_undo     +vertsplit
+emacs_tags     +mouse_dec     -sun_workshop        +xterm_clipboard
```

First question, use `"+y` can't copy the current line to clipboard, and `"+yy` could copy current line to clipboard. I don't know why.

And If I set `vnoremap <leader>y "+y`, use commmand `<leader>yy` in vim can't work (what I expect is `<leader>yy` action as same as `"+yy`).

What's more, is there a way set a mapping to let `<leader>yny` action as same as `"+yny`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Finally, found `noremap <leader>y "+y` works, not `vnoremap`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you seriously misunderstand how vi and vim work. See `:help y`, `:help operator`, and `:help movement`. IMHO the most of vim's appeal is in the logic of combinations of operators and motions.

The first `y` is *operator* (*y*ank), the second one is *motion* - and in vim most, if not all, operators when repeated work on the whole line (`dd` - delete line, `cc` - change line.)

I am not at all sure what you expect `"+yny` would do, but it is copying (`y`) into clipboard (`"+`) from current location to next occurrence of search term (`n`), and then starting another copy (`y`) and waiting for *motion*.